# wifi connectivity Issues on Sony Viao

Tags: 12.04

unable to connect to wifi on Sony Viao, after initial setup and update?

Do I unistall the update?

Running version 12.04

Regards

Albert

Answer (score 0):

> sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf

then add

> options ath9k nohwcrypt=1